# Double spaces caused by biblatex \volcite

Tags: spacing, biblatex, citing

I encountered some double (i.e. too wide) spaces in front of my BibLaTeX references today, and it turns out these only crop up with `\volcite` when using a postnote.
Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english, UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=british,english=british]{csquotes}
\selectlanguage{UKenglish}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

There are various opinions on this matter.
A very silly one is given by \pvolcite{1}[45]{Book1}.

A more clever approach has been suggested in \volcite{2}[45]{Book2}.

I propose to follow a middle course, as suggested by \volcite{2}[45]{Book3}.

\end{document}
```

On my system this examples produces ugly wide spaces before the names of the authors. These disappear once I remove the `[45]` postnotes.

I presume there is a comment `%` lacking somewhere, but I am using a standard style in the example. Any ideas as to where the problem can be found?

I am currently using MikTeX 2.9 with BibLaTeX 1.6 and Biber 0.9.4.

Answer (score 3):

Your presumption was correct -- a comment sign is missing in the definition of `\blx@volcitecmd@iii`. Please report this bug at [sourceforge.biblatex](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=1126005&group_id=244752&func=browse).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@volcitecmd@iii#1[#2]{%
  \blx@getformat\blx@tempc{ffd}{}{volcitepages}%
  \edef\blx@tempa{\expandonce\blx@tempa[{%
    \expandonce{\blx@tempb{#1}}%
    \noexpand\addcomma\noexpand\space
    \expandonce{\blx@tempc{#2}}}]}% <--- THIS COMMENT SIGN WAS MISSING
  \blx@tempa}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

I propose to follow a middle course, as suggested by \volcite{2}[45]{A01}.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: This bug was fixed in `biblatex` v1.7, released at November 13th, 2011.

Comment: Bug reported. Thanks a lot, I needed this fixed before the next version is released.